# Linux: Hostname to Spring Cloud Web Application not recognized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hostname, hystrix

I have a development environment in windows where I can access the spring build in both IP Address and Hostname(PC-Name) for my Eureka Config Server / Client. When I move it to the RedHat environment it does not recognize the URL if it is a hostname.

My main goal is to change the eureka client status page to point to the hysterix monitor for the eureka client's hysterix stream. The value of **${spring.cloud.client.hostname}** resolves to the hostname. I was wondering what is the way to make it the current IP of the eureka client?

To be exact here is an example of what I want am trying to do.

```
eureka:
 instance:
  preferIPAddress: true
  statusPageUrlPath: http://${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${eureka.cloud.config.port}/hystrix/monitor?stream=http%3A%2F%2F${spring.cloud.client.hostname}%3A${server.port}%2Factuator%2Fhystrix.stream
```

It just so happen that the client and the server are both in the same machine so I am contented in using the client hostname for both the **Eureka Config Server** path and the **Eureka Client hystrix stream**.

Note that I already set the **preferIPAddress** to true but the generated hostname is still the value of "/etc/hostname". I saw some solution that explicitly specifies the IP Address in the Eureka Client Instance. But I prefer to make it dynamic so that the same code can run smoothly on either Development and Deploy environment.

What can I do so that the hostname can also be recognized the same as the ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has dawn upon me just now. I just changed the following to this.

> ${spring.cloud.client.hostname}

```
    ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
```

> ${spring.cloud.client.ip-address}

I was thrown to a wrong conclusion because other sites would tell me to use this configuration **${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}** which does not work.

Probably there was a change in Finchley / Spring boot 2.0 version. If anyone can give me a link to a documentation or discussion describing the configuration change, it would be helpful.